# How to name method for setting boolean variable

Tags: c++, naming, conventions

I have boolean variable, which tells me if user has his own text (I have text edit widget in GUI) or if I should load from a file, called `hasOwnText`.

I am using it only inside of a class, so I don't need any getter, however I need to set it from outside depending on checkBox from GUI. The question is how the method should be named?

I've always named them like `setHasOwnText` and I don't know it just doesn't seem that good to me. Could it be somehow improved?

Also if my variable is named `hasOwnText` and if I ever need getter, should I just name it `getHasOwnText`?

Thank you

Comment: @MrPromethee Conventions are different for different languages, and C++ in particular doesn't really have any widely accepted rules. Perhaps this should just be closed as too opinionated, but I wanted to see if anyone came up with a good C++-specific answer first.

Comment: _Naming_ things right appears to me sometimes more complicated than _implementing_ things right. (Colleagues told me the same.) I usually follow what I recognize as convention in the 3rd party API I like currently most / essentially build my application on. (Sometimes, these conventions are even documented as "rules".)

Comment: `setHasOwnText` seems to be wrong, because it suggests that there is second method `setOwnText` and that the client would have to use them correctly (aka they can be used incorrectly). If you do have a `setOwnText` then that method should set the `bool`. Anyhow, I am just speculating and in fact only you can know what the best name would be

Comment: Well I actually have method `setOwnText` which sets actual text :D. I mean, I did not ask this to be showed some rule and told "it is like this", I just wanted to see others opinions. I guess I just leave it as is then. Thank you

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There are two common patterns for getters and setters:

```
int someValue();              // getter
void someValue(int newValue); // setter
```

or alternatively:

```
int getSomeValue();
void setSomeValue(int newValue);
```

At first, even though you don't need a getter, I'd provide one anyway, by principle. If a user can set a value (be it you yourself or anyone else), she/he might want to know some time later which value she/he actually set a while ago without having to remember separately. For booleans, I'm totally fine with first pattern, too:

```
isSomething(true); // or has
if(isSomething()) { }
```

With second pattern, while 'get' is replaced with 'is'/'has', I'd still just prepend 'set' prefix:

```
setHasSomething(true);
if(hasSomething()) { }
```